# Creating new nodes using redistribute_vertices

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I am working on a graph flow model in the context of transport networks. I have the position of sensors (lat/lon) and would like to associate these sensors with nodes on a graph retrieved using osmnx.

At present, I use `get_nearest_node` to map a sensor to a node. However, this isn't optimal, as I'm at the mercy of the cartographer -- straight roads will be have fewer nodes, and so the mean displacement (and therefore error) will be higher, even when dealing with unsimplified graphs. I had considered using `get_nearest_edge`, but I'd still need to edit the graph to insert a new node at the position of the sensor.

Instead, I thought a reasonable way of achieving this would be to upsample the graph (perhaps using `redistribute_vertices`), applying `get_nearest_node`, and then re-simplifying the graph, but somehow whitelisting the node that is now associated with a sensor to prevent it from being removed.

However, it's not clear to me how to go from the output of `redistribute_vertices` to a graph -- it returns a `LineString` or `MultiLineString` rather than a new graph.

I saw this question posted on the osmnx GitHub project: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/304, in which a GeoDataFrame is generated, with a new column containing the redistributed way as a (`Multi`)`LineString`. However, I'm not sure how I can map this new gdf back to a Graph -- the corresponding `node` dataframe hasn't been updated, and `u` and `v` values remain the same in the new edges table.

Any pointers (including telling me I'm going about this the wrong way and should be using function `XYZ`) would be really appreciated.

Comment: No easy answer there. Unsimplified graphs are an easy way to make it more fine-grained, but may not work if your straight roads are too long. If you go the redistribute_vertices route, you'll have to convert those vertices to nodes, add those nodes to a (new?) graph, add new edges connecting those nodes, and then do a nearest node search.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @gboeing (and thanks for your hard work writing and maintaining osmnx).

I will try hacking some code together that creates new nodes based on the output of `redistribute_vertices`. If I get something together, I'll share the code here as an answer.

One additional question: I mentioned "whitelisting the node that is now associated with a sensor to prevent it from being removed". Is this something supported by osmnx, or would I need to hack `osmnx.simplification.simplify_graph` to facilitate this?

Comment: You'll have to hack. But off the top of my head it'd be relatively easy: just edit the [_is_endpoint](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/v0.15.1/osmnx/simplification.py#L15) function to return True if the node is in your predefined whitelist of nodes.